# Not able to install app using adb command

Tags: adb, installation, apk, broken-screen

I have a broken screen in my device due to that i am not able to take back of contact and other data.

I am trying to use vysor chrome plugin which installs an app and cast the screen in to web browser.

When i try to use vysor application, i am not able to install the app in device. I am always getting below error

```
adb install com.koushikdutta.vysor.apk

2660 KB/s (2958940 bytes in 1.086s)
Please select on your phone whether can install the app by The ADB command?
```

refused to install the app by The ADB command !

I tried to install the app using pm command as well but observed the same issue.

Note : - Same issue is observed for all the apks.
Device details : - LeTv Le 2

Comment: Which android version?

Comment: It seems like a prompt is asking for your approval.

Comment: What @esQmo_ said is right; lots of Chinese phones implement such extra "security" measures to prevent USB-sourced malicious installs.

Answer (score 1):

For LeTv Le 2, Go to Settings > Fingerprint & Password > Other Security Options > Install apps in background , Set this options to Yes.